# How to perform KNN Classification to consider a customer data?

Tags: r, data-mining, knn

Q: Consider the following customer.
Age=40,  Experience=10,  Income=84, Family=2, CCAvg=2, Education_2=1, Education_3=0, Mortgage=0, Securities Account=0, CD Account=0, Online=1 and Credit Card=1. Perform a k-NN classification with all predicators except ID and ZIP code using the k-value.

I managed to get the K-value but I don't think of how to perform Knn to consider a specific user data. How can I create knn classification to consider the customer?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have learnt the appropriate k and created your knn classifier with all the training data, you can compute the k nearest neighbors for a specific user/customer.

From those k nearest neighbors, you would compute the probabilities of the output variable to predict based on the output values of your k neighbors.

For eg., if it is a binary classifier(output class has 2 possible values), and suppose 80% of your k neighbors have one output value (1) and 20% have the other(0). In that case, your prediction would be -

```
Class 0     Class 1
  0.2          0.8
```

Hope that helps.